# How to use html5 jasper report from java layer without publishing report to jasper server

Tags: html, highcharts, jasper-reports

I am new to jasper and highcharts. I have designed my html5 report using jaspersoft license version.

I want to use that html5 jasper report from my java application without publishing it to jasper server.

Which jars I need to include to fill that html5 jasper report from java. so that I will generate html markup of report.

I have tried these jars

jasperreports-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-chart-themes-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-fonts-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-fusion-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-highcharts-5.0.0.jar
jasperreports-pro-5.0.0.jar and some more jasper server jars.

and code

```
String fileName = "C://test.jasper";
File file= new File(fileName);
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, (new HashMap<String,        
Object>()), databaseConfiguration.getConnection());
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
```

But after running this it ask me some other jars/configuration of jasper server. I am adding  more jars and configuration from jasper server but still not able to fill the report.

I cannot use jasper server or publish report on jasper server.

Please help me.Some code snippet or link to documentation will also be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I know how to use simple jasper reports from java and I have done that part. I am facing problem with HTML5/highcharts jasper reports only. I do have license. But still not able to fill that report.